# Can x64 pointers be formatted like WinDbg does it without manually breaking them into two pieces?

Tags: c++

I am using C++ in native mode with Visual Studio 2017.  I also use WinDbg and one of the nice things about it is that it separates the higher 32 bits from the lower 32 bits of a pointer as shown below:

> 000007fe`fd760000

which is nice and makes the pointer easier to read and get a feel for.

It's easy to do that by breaking the 64 bit pointer into two parts but, I couldn't help wonder if WinDbg was using a format specification that I am not aware of to display pointers the way it does.

**my question is:** is there a format spec that can be used in printf to obtain a pointer formatted as WinDbg does without breaking/separating the pointer into two pieces ?

IOW, is something like this possible: printf("%magicformat: ", pointer64) that would yield the result shown by WinDbg ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Choose a language, C or C++.  C++ has user-defined stream manipulators, unlike `printf`.

Comment: The question isn't about C++, it's about a format specification in printf which is available in both C and C++.

Comment: The only official way to format a pointer is to use the `%p` specifier. The actual format is implementation-defined.